# File Server Directory Structure

Tags: windows, network-share, file-sharing, windows-server-2019

Let's say I have 3 main directories that need to be shared, I'll call them "Management", "Finance" and "Sales". There seems to be two logical ways of doing this: either I share each folder individually, or I share the parent directory.

[image: Example of both share methods]

Sharing the parent directory would be easier to set up, and also has the benefit of allowing files to be moved between directories without copying. Sharing each folder individually would give shorter file names, for example: `\\File_Server\Management` instead of `\\File_Server\Shared\Management`.

Is either option considered "best practice"? What are the benefits/drawbacks of each method?

Comment: It depends on how you want to control access to the folders.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Access in controlled with NTFS permissions, so either way should give the same results.

Comment: Or, more to the point, access control to entire shares.

Answer (score 1):

**A single share**

- Less configuration both on the server and clients
- Easy moves allowed

**Dedicated shares**

- You'll be able to show to user only shares they need to see (access control)
- If you ever need to split them to different devices on a server or even different servers, that'll be less painful to do

In our environment, we opted to "single share" variant, but there are cases when 2nd is better.